# DataInputStream printing unknown character from a socket

Tags: java, printwriter, datainputstream, inputstreamreader

I'm getting an unknown character when reading from a socket using `DataInputStream`. When I send "Hello" on the server side the output is "Hello" the unknown character is the issue. I'm new to socket programming so I don't know what the issue could be. I tried using a `BufferReader` and `PrintWriter` too bu the server when using `readLine()` does not print the text sent but rather `java.io.BufferedReader`.

Server Side:

```
//BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
DataInputStream is= new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
String userinput= is.readLine();
System.out.println("Client message: "+userinput);
```

Client Side:

```
//BufferedReader std= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String userInput;
DataOutputStream out;
while((userInput=std.readLine()) !=null){
    Socket socketClient= new Socket("localhost",5000);
    OutputStream os= socketClient.getOutputStream();
    out=new DataOutputStream(os);
    out.writeUTF(userInput);
    out.flush();
    socketClient.close();
}
```

Comment: `writeUTF()` doesn't write a line, and it doesn't just write the bytes. It writes a length word first. See the Javadoc. If you send with `writeUTF()` you must receive with `readUTF()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `writeUTF` on the client side, are you sure `readLine` on the server side is compatible with it? I had never seen that before, but the javadoc mentions it's a ["modified" UTF-8 encoding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#modified-utf-8). Try using `readUTF` instead, or simply use the regular `write` method.

Comment: I only need to send a string which can be composed of multiple lines and be able to read it. For now this is a solution I found. As I said I was trying to use BufferReader but I was unable to find a good source online that does it

Comment: Is there a better way to do this? I need to be able to send an String of multiple lines that i can parse later. But sending and reading data from sockets I'm not sure what is the better solution.

Comment: Well if you want to use a `BufferedReader` or a `BufferedInputStream` it's quite simple, you can just call this constructor which wraps an `InputStream`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html#BufferedInputStream(java.io.InputStream)

Comment: I'll take a look. If I wanted to send a string which option is the most effective?

Comment: If you're using a buffered input stream it should be fit for most purposes. There are plenty of examples of this online

Comment: Yes, I tried to use a buffer reader but I did not get the server to print the data correctly instead i get a message to the one specified in the question with an address

Answer (score -1):

If you read a UTF line then you can write UTF or ASCII characters but as opposed to if you read ASCII characters then you must write those characters as ASCII.
try to use `out.write(userInput);` instead of `out.writeUTF(userInput);`

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'UTF line'.

Comment: i meant a couple of characters not a line delimited by \n @user207421